# hyper link that shows confirmation msg box

Tags: html, jsp, confirm

I want to use a hyperlink that shows a confirmation msg box. It will process it if 'yes' selected otherwise not.

for example...

```
<a href="delete?id="+12>delete</a>
```

that shows a msg box for confirmation do you want to delete if yes then it executes the delete servlet otherwise not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with this simple but very effective solution

```
<a href="Your link if use click yes" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')">Link</a>
```

This will redirect to the given link if user Confirms.

Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ajoegw08/) you can check it here.

Answer (score 0):

why dont you write an onclick method (for the hyperlink in javascript) and request for a confirmation, if yes, redirect else throw some error or do some other action.